# Trying to update a slideshow with time interval

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

I'm looking to update a site for some friends with a pretty simple request (to change the time on each slide from ~5 sec -> 15 sec) but can't find the parameters where I'd be able to change the length of time. I'm not by any means an expert, but the site was built by someone who is no longer on board and we just want to fix this element... Any help you can offer would be appreciated --

Here is the CSS related to the slideshow:

```css
.slideshow{
 position:relative;
 background:#000;
}
.slideshow img,
.slidegallery img{
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
.slideshow .slide {
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:1;
 left:0;
 top:0;
}
.slideshow .slide.active { z-index:2; }
.pagination {
 position:absolute;
 bottom:28px;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:100;
 text-align:center;
}
.pagination ul {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 line-height:0;
}
.pagination ul li {
 margin:0 5px;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 list-style:none;
}
.pagination a {
 width:13px;
 height:13px;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 display:block;
 border-radius:50%;
 background:#fff;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.pagination a:hover, .pagination li.active a { background:#ffcf00; }
.home .caption-holder{
 max-width:1250px;
 margin:0 auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.slideshow .caption{
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:29px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 color:#fff;
 position:absolute;
 left:40px;
 bottom:118px;
 padding:0 32px;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.slideshow p { margin:0; }
.slideshow h2 {
 margin:0 0 6px;
 font-size:31px;
 line-height:35px;
 font-weight:300;
 color:#ffca00;
 letter-spacing:-1px;
}
.home .slideshow .slide .caption{
 width:491px;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:14px;
}
.slideshow .holder {
 padding:3.2% 6.5% 4.3%;
 line-height:18px;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.slideshow .btn-next,
.slideshow .btn-prev {
 width:32px;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 right:0;
 top:0;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 background:#fc0;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.slideshow .btn-prev {
 right:auto;
 left:0;
}
.slideshow .btn-next:after,
.slideshow .btn-prev:after{
 width:10px;
 height:18px;
 position:absolute;
 content:'';
 top:50%;
 right:50%;
 margin:-9px -5px 0 0;
 background:url(images/social-networks.png) no-repeat -219px 0;
}
.slideshow .btn-prev:after { background-position:-198px 0; }
.slideshow .slide.second .caption, .slideshow .slide.third .caption, .slideshow .slide.fourth .caption {padding:3px 5px 3px 19px;}
.slideshow .slide.fourth .caption {
 width:727px;
 text-indent:7px;
 padding:0;
}
.slideshow .slide.fourth .next-btn, .slideshow .slide.fourth .prev-btn{height:30px;}
.slideshow .slide.fifth .caption{
 background:none;
}
```

and the .php from the template that populates the slideshow:

```html
<?php if ($projects = get_field('home_gallery')): ?>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <div class="slideset">
            <?php global $post; ?>
            <?php foreach($projects as $slide):  ?>
                <div class="slide">
                    <?php echo get_theme_image($slide['image'],'full',array(),true) ?>
                    <div class="caption-holder">
                        <?php $post = $slide['project']; ?>
                        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>    
                            <div class="caption">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-next"><?php _e('next button','pyramidpremierproperties'); ?></a><a href="#" class="btn-prev"><?php _e('previous button','pyramidpremierproperties'); ?></a>
                                <div class="holder">
                                    <?php the_title('<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">','</a></h2>'); ?>
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;  ?>
        </div>
        <div class="pagination"><?php _e('&nbsp;','pyramidpremierproperties'); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the JS I could find that seems relevant -- tried changing the switchtime and animspeed but doesnt seem to be making a difference...

```js
/*
 * jQuery SlideShow plugin
 */
;(function($){
 function FadeGallery(options) {
  this.options = $.extend({
   slides: 'ul.slideset > li',
   activeClass:'active',
   disabledClass:'disabled',
   btnPrev: 'a.btn-prev',
   btnNext: 'a.btn-next',
   generatePagination: false,
   pagerList: '<ul>',
   pagerListItem: '<li><a href="#"></a></li>',
   pagerListItemText: 'a',
   pagerLinks: '.pagination li',
   currentNumber: 'span.current-num',
   totalNumber: 'span.total-num',
   btnPlay: '.btn-play',
   btnPause: '.btn-pause',
   btnPlayPause: '.btn-play-pause',
   galleryReadyClass: 'gallery-js-ready',
   autorotationActiveClass: 'autorotation-active',
   autorotationDisabledClass: 'autorotation-disabled',
   autorotationStopAfterClick: false,
   circularRotation: true,
   switchSimultaneously: true,
   disableWhileAnimating: false,
   disableFadeIE: false,
   autoRotation: false,
   pauseOnHover: true,
   autoHeight: false,
   useSwipe: false,
   swipeThreshold: 15,
   switchTime: 4000,
   animSpeed: 600,
   event:'click'
  }, options);
  this.init();
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As far as I can tell, there is nothing allowing the slideshow to automatically change slide in the provided code. Is there also javascript involved that you could add to your question?

Comment: You might need to find where you're initializing the plugin. The code you found seems the plugin itself. If an interval is set in the initialization call, it will overwrite any value you are setting here.

Answer (score 0):

The `switchTime` option in your javascript looks promising. Also, I'm not sure what jQuery SlideShow plugin you are using but it's possible you aren't setting the time on each slide but instead just using the default time of this plugin.